# Java version for Tomcat

Tags: debian, java, version, tomcat

I want to run my Tomcat with Java 7 but all I found about configuring it doesn't work. The management interface of Tomcat shows `1.6.0_24-b24` as Java version. The `JAVA_HOME` variable is empty.

```
% echo $JAVA_HOME
```

I understand that in this case Tomcat uses the system default Java, which should be 7.

```
% java -version
java version "1.7.0_09"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.3) (7u9-2.3.3-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
```

I changed it with `update-alternatives`.

What part of the configuration am I missing?

Comment: The command `update-java-alternatives` will update all java related alternatives.

Comment: Did do it. Sadly no changes :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the right configuration file my self. It is `/etc/default/tomcat`. There I was able to set

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

and it works now.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yup, this is right. On most systems, you don't have access to the tomcat user in a way you can set JAVA_HOME. You have two choices: change the Java in use by the whole system to a single one or tweak it the way you show here.

Answer (score 0):

export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/java/environment
Then run tomcat.

You can do this in the users .bash_profile as well.

Comment: This doesn't work either. Set it to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64` which is now shown by `echo $JAVA_HOME` as well as `sudo -u tomcat7 echo $JAVA_HOME`. Tomcat still starts with the wrong version.

Comment: I can confirm that this does not help. Even if you put JAVA_HOME=your new java in the /etc/environment and reboot, and do the alternatives thing,  tomcat still picks up the old version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I am using tomcat 9. I decided to define the configurations in **catalina.sh**.

This is however for *nix

```
$ cd /apache-tomcat-9.0.21/bin/
$ vim catalina.sh

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.12
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.12
```

ensure to restart your tomcat

```
$ ./startup.sh
```

Comment: Modifying `catalina.sh` is not a good idea (it might get overwritten by an upgrade). Create a `setenv.sh` file in the same directory (it is sourced by `catalina.sh` whenever present).